# Getting TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xml, fetch-api

I can't fetch data and don't know what am doing wrong. If I paste link in browser I get response fine, so the API key is good. Format is in XML so I also converted it, as you can see down below, and in 'Response Headers' I get status 200 OK.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

function Api() {

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("https://www.goodreads.com/author/list/18541?format=xml&key=TftQypHkudfH0VZcukEWtg")
            .then(res => res.text())
            .then(data => {
                let parser = new DOMParser()
                let xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(data, 'text/xml')
                console.log(xmlDoc)
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }, [])

    return (
        <div></div>
    )
}

export default Api
```

Here is snippet
[image]

EDIT

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that in the console you get an error concerning `CORS policy`

You need to set up a proxy in order to overcome this issue. It's simple and easy, the method is briefly explained [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/)

EDIT: Another way to setup a proxy is the following:

Install as dev dependency [http-proxy-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware)

`npm install --save-dev http-proxy-middleware`

Then create a file named `setupProxy.js` in your project's `src` directory

Paste the following code there:

```js
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware')
const serverUrl = 'https://www.goodreads.com';

const options = {
    target: serverUrl,
    changeOrigin: true
};


module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use('/api/*', proxy(options));
    app.use('/api/author/list/*', proxy(options));
};
```

Then fetch your request like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/api/author/list/18541?format=xml&key=TftQypHkudfH0VZcukEWtg")
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(data => {
            let parser = new DOMParser()
            let xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(data, 'text/xml')
            console.log(xmlDoc)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}, [])
```

If you need to fetch a different URL pattern in the same source, for example

`https://www.goodreads.com/author/somethingelse/id`

you add a new entry in the list of proxy URLs like this:

`app.use('/api/author/somethingelse/*', proxy(options));`

Comment: Tnx! I've already made it successfully with 2 steps written down below, but thanks anyway :) I didn't know that I have to put "https://www.goodreads.com" in proxy, I thought it should be like they wrote, with localhost ("http://localhost:3000")

Answer (score 1):

So basically, what I needed to do is:

1) add `"proxy": "https://www.goodreads.com"` to my package.json

2) remove that piece of url from fetch function, so it should look like this:

`fetch("/author/list/18541?format=xml&key=TftQypHkudfH0VZcukEWtg")`

instead of this:

`fetch("https://www.goodreads.com/author/list/18541?format=xml&key=TftQypHkudfH0VZcukEWtg")`

and no more CORS policy and errors :)